# Why is the first $p$-adic congruence subgroup a pro-$p$ group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, p-groups, pro-p-groups, matrix-congruences

I am trying to see that $\Gamma_2$, defined as the kernel of the natural  surjective map $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb Z_p)\to \text{GL}(\mathbb F_p)$ is a pro-$p$ group. So I'm trying to show that every finite quotient is a $p$-group.

As my first attempt, I'm trying to show that if there is a map $$\phi: \Gamma \to \mathbb Z/l\mathbb Z$$
then it has to be trivial. Since the right side is abelian, the kernel of this map contains the commutator subgroup.

I'm guessing that I want to show that the commutator is open, therefore closed and of finite index so that the left side will be recognizable $p$-group but beyond that I don't know. Even this will not solve the problem because I need to replace the $\mathbb Z/l\mathbb Z$ above with an arbitrary simple group and that case seems hard..

EDIT: I just noticed that $\Gamma_2$ contains the subgroup of matrices of the form $\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & m \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right]$ for all $m\in p\mathbb Z_p$ so maybe this is helpful?

Thanks for your help and I hope I've shown enough of my work. If not please let me know and I'll try to add a bit more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any whole number $n$ there is a surjection $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})\to\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$, Let $K_n$ be the kernel of this map. Then we have an infinite commutative diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
& & \vdots  \\
& K_3 @>>> \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^3\mathbb{Z}) \\
@VVV @VVV \\
& K_2 @>>> \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}) \\
@VVV @VVV \\
& K_1 @>>> \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})
\end{CD}$$

The kernel of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)\to\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ will be the inverse limit $\varprojlim K_n$.

Now compute $|K_n|$ to find it is a $p$-group for all $n$. Note all matrices in $K_n$ are expressible in the form $I+pA$ where $I$ is the identity matrix and $A$ is an arbitrary $2\times 2$ matrix over $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you. Just to confirm: $K_n$ is basically $(\mathbb Z/p^{n-1}\mathbb Z)^4$ so it's a $p$-group right?

Comment: @Ariadne I wouldn't call it that, but there's an obvious bijection with the entries yes.